# Loading xml file into uwp application c#

Tags: c#, xml, uwp, byte-order-mark

I'm loading an xml file from installed location into the local folder using the code below.

```
        // Has the file been copied already?
        bool blFileExist = false;
        try
        {
            await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("settings.xml");
            // No exception means it exists
            blFileExist = true;
        }
        catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
        {
            // The file obviously doesn't exist
            blFileExist = false;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

        if (!blFileExist)
        {
            try
            {
                // Cant await inside catch
                StorageFile file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("settings.xml");
                await file.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
            }
            catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
            {

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
```

I then load it when necessary using this.

```
    private async void loadSettings()
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("settings.xml");
            using (Stream fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
            {
                doc = XElement.Load(fileStream);
            }

        }
        catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Finally I save it back to the local folder using this.

```
    private async void saveSettings()
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("settings.xml");
            using (Stream fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
            {
                //Save URLs
                doc.Save(fileStream);
            }
        }
        catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Code compiles, runs and doesn't throw any errors but doesn't do as expected. When loading the file using the code in the second code block it steps out of the code and goes back to the method that calls it as if throwing an error and stepping into a catch block when it reaches the line

```
using (Stream fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
```

Not entirely sure but I think it might be down to encoding and the byte order mark. Any suggestions?

Here's the xml in question.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <settings>
    <feeds>
      <url name="All">http://services.parliament.uk/calendar/all.rss</url>
      <url name="CommonsMainChamber">http://services.parliament.uk/calendar/commons_main_chamber.rss</url>
      <url name="CommonsSelectCommittee">http://services.parliament.uk/calendar/commons_select_committee.rss</url>
      <url name="CommonsGeneralCommittee">http://services.parliament.uk/calendar/commons_general_committee.rss</url>
      <url name="CommonsWestminsterHall">http://services.parliament.uk/calendar/commons_westminster_hall.rss</url>
      <url name="LordsMainChamber">http://services.parliament.uk/calendar/lords_main_chamber.rss</url>
      <url name="LordsGrandCommittee">http://services.parliament.uk/calendar/lords_grand_committee.rss</url>
      <url name="LordsSelectCommittee">http://services.parliament.uk/calendar/lords_select_committee.rss</url>
      <url name="ParliamentaryNews">http://www.parliament.uk/g/RSS/news-feed/?pageInstanceId=209</url>
      <url name="CommonsNews">http://www.parliament.uk/g/RSS/news-feed/?pageInstanceId=25366</url>
      <url name="LordsNews">http://www.parliament.uk/g/RSS/news-feed/?pageInstanceId=25367</url>
      <url name="CommitteeNews">http://www.parliament.uk/g/RSS/news-feed/?pageInstanceId=25388</url>
      <url name="CommonsBriefingPapers">http://researchbriefings.parliament.uk/rssfeed/Commons%20Briefing%20papers</url>
      <url name="LordsLibraryNotes">http://researchbriefings.parliament.uk/rssfeed/Lords%20Library%20notes</url>
      <url name="LordsInFocus">http://researchbriefings.parliament.uk/rssfeed/Lords%20In%20Focus</url>
      <url name="POSTBriefs">http://researchbriefings.parliament.uk/rssfeed/POSTbriefs</url>
      <url name="POSTNotes">http://researchbriefings.parliament.uk/rssfeed/POSTnotes</url>
      <url name="EarlyDayMotions">http://www.parliament.uk/g/rss/generic/?pageInstanceId=78055&type=Edms</url>
    </feeds>
 </settings>
```

Comment: When it gets in the catch block what is the exception?

Comment: What's the contents of the settings.xml file?

Comment: Ken, as I said, it's not throwing any errors that I'm aware of.

Comment: mm8, virtually nothing! `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<settings>
  <ai_players>4</ai_players>
  <back>Back_0</back>
</settings>`

Comment: I think the location where file settings.xml is stored is wrong.

Comment: @jdweng Tried that thought. That's why they're all stripped back to just being placed at root of the path.

Comment: What root path?  The project?

Comment: @jdweng The root of the installation folder and that of the isolated storage/local folder or whatever it is these days!

Comment: Just a gut feel: it might be a rights issue.

Comment: @luigivampa `it steps out of the code and goes back to the method that calls it as if throwing an error and stepping into a catch block when it reaches the line` I agree with Ken's point, it should get exception message in `try...catch` block. Anyway, if you still cannot solve this issue. Please provide [mcve], so that, we can help you diagnose it quickly.

Comment: If your code goes to catch block, then if you have `catch (Exception exc)` what `exc.Message` says? Can you compare the `doc` loaded from file with original `settings.xml`? Can you put the sample content of your settings.xml to your question? Can you make a sample app with the problem and share it?

Comment: @luigivampa can you make sure that the file is copied from the installed location to the LocalFolder by putting a check before getting the readstream. var item = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.TryGetItemAsync("settings.xml");

Comment: @Jerryway Thanks for the reply. If there's a fault in the code agreed throwing an error might give me an idea of where to start but it doesn't! I call the loadSettings() method and watching it step through from a breakpoint it reaches the line using () and then exits the method as if return; had been called.

Comment: @Saurabh Thanks for the reply. I've expanded on the code I use in the first code block. I test for the file there to see if it needs writing to the local folder. It appears to.

Comment: @Romasz Hello, thanks for the reply. It's not throwing errors, like I said, it's just stepping out of the method as if return; is called. Can't compare the loaded from file because I can't get the bugger to load!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that your issue was in your XML file. Please check the last url's value. The XML file really contains an "&" character.

```
<url name="EarlyDayMotions">http://www.parliament.uk/g/rss/generic/?pageInstanceId=78055&type=Edms</url>
```

A real "&" on it's own breaks XML files.

You could use `&amp;` in place of `&`, then your code would work.